# Asterisk IVR to Extension slow

Tags: sip, asterisk

I have a IVR set to pickup our PSTN lines and tell the user to enter the extension OR to press 1 for a representative. If the person enters an extension it transfers within 1 second , but if they press 1 asterisk goes silent for 5-10 seconds before it starts ringing the phones in a Hunt group. Below is the pastebin with the Full log while I call in and press 1.

http://pastebin.com/MRD1CFfT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system is waiting for further input to determine whether the complete extension is '1' or something else that starts with '1'.

Do you have other extensions in that context that start with the number 1? Check your dialplan.

Comment: crap. Beat me too it. But this. Your system is waiting for a pre-determined time for more input. You need to find where this is enabled and shorten it to 2 seconds or something

Comment: Or better, remove the other extensions that start with '1' from that context. If you can. :)

Comment: @MikeyB Note that even if we use another number like 8 the issue still occurs. Our extensions in the 100 zone.

Comment: The issue will occur regardless of the single digit re-route you're trying to press. Your system is configured to wait for a set amount of time unless 3 digits are pressed. You need to shorten the overall time or the time allowed between button presses to fix this

Comment: Do you know what in the Dial plan I need to change?

Comment: Not offhand, have you tried googling for it? Or checking SF for the answer? Or asking it on SF if you can't find the answer to that?